# Can someone explain to me why the keyword `this`, in these arrow functions, ends up with the given values in these examples

Tags: javascript

According to (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

> An arrow function does not have its own this. The this value of the
> enclosing lexical scope is used; arrow functions follow the normal
> variable lookup rules.

Here's some examples of where what I thought was the arrow function's `this` is wrong. (I have not embedded runable code into the question because it gives me different results than my code-editor - Visual Studio Code that's running with node). Could someone explain my examples?

**1.**

```
f = param1 => console.log(this);

f(); //expected: global object prints: {}
```

**2.**

```
var bike = {
    owner: 'Adam',
    getOwner: () => {
        console.log(this.owner);
    }
};

bike.getOwner(); //expected: 'Adam' prints: undefined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> An arrow function does not have its own this. The this value of the enclosing lexical scope is used; arrow functions follow the normal variable lookup rules.

So what you need to think of is, what would `this` refer to if it wasn't in it's own function?

So if we have an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE), like:

```
(() => console.log(this.foo))();
```

this is equivalent to

```
console.log(this.foo)
```

So, using your example:

```js
var bike = {
    owner: 'Adam',
    getOwner: (() => {
        console.log(this.owner);
    })()
};
```

is equivalent to:

```js
var bike = {
    owner: 'Adam',
    getOwner: console.log(this.owner)
};
```

and obviously, `this.owner` doesn't exist.

You could also think of an arrow function as a regular function where you `.bind(this)` to it:

```js
this.tmp = 'a';

x = () => {
    console.log(this.tmp);
}

y = function() {
    console.log(this.tmp);
}.bind(this)

x();
y();
```

Comment: Best explanation I've ever read for arrow functions "what would this refer to if it wasn't in it's own function".

Comment: That makes sense to think of it as 'what would the `this` refer to if it were outside the arrow function'. `this` refers to the global object and because the global object doesn't have a property called 'owner' it returns back `undefined`?

Comment: exactly, at least in the example it refers to the global object, it could refer to something else depending on the context.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not running the code in a browser (or Node). In both of your examples, `this` refers to the global object.

Probably wherever you're running the code doesn't provide the usual global object (faster? more secure?) and instead provides `{}`.

Comment: I hear what you're saying. I am using node and have printed out global objects before.

Comment: Then I'm unsure as to why you get this behavior in #1 (but you understood the specs right, it should be the global object). As for #2, you seem to have a misconception of what the arrow function would do there and you should read the answer @dave wrote https://stackoverflow.com/a/62599859/2306481

Answer (score -1):

In your case, using traditional function keyword instead of lambda function solves the problem.

```
var bike = {
owner: 'Adam',
getOwner: function() {
    console.log(this.owner);
}};
bike.getOwner();
```

Comment: The OP didn't ask for how to get their expected answers; they asked for an explanation of the *actual* answers. (downvote)

Answer (score -1):

well they are two cases for `this` keyword the global Object which is window in the browser or Global in Node JS and the second case is object if it called within any method of that object. so if you called function or run it in the global scope it will refer to the global object as I mentioned before either if it is an arrow function or ordinary function for example:

```
function foo () {
   console.log(this);
}
let bar = () => console.log(this);
foo() // window
bar() // window
```

the second case it will refer to the object for example:

```
let obj = {
  name: "john doe",
  sayName(){
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}
obj.sayName() // john doe
```

I hope this will explain you what is the heck of this keyword

Answer (score -2):

For arrow functions, do not require to bind. takes the reference of where the arrow function has defintion.

1 point - This will print the props where the arrow was defined

2 point - is compilation successful, because colon are not suppose to be with arrow function is this fashion.

How are you trying the execution of this code!